# Registricting folder access based on .htaccess and cookie variable

Tags: .htaccess, restriction

I need to add a condition in .htaccess file to check if a user is logged in (cookie value SESS@@@@@@@) and based on the condition i need to grant access to folder.

Sample Cookie name: SESS12312312132ABD or SESSACBBCBBCBCBCCB (SESS is prefixed for every cookie value)

I tried with below condition but not working

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !SESS.* [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://www.google.com
</IfModule>
```

Appreciate your suggestion

Comment: What exactly isn't working for you? The rule you posted redirects your site visitors to `example.com` if the cookie name or value doesn't match the pattern `SESS.*` .

Comment: @AmitVerma Thanks for your response!
The above code always goes to else clause and redirects to example.com. 

I even tried creating a new cookie and assinging a value and valiting it with the specific value. I still see the same issue always redirects to example.com. I am wondering if .htaccess file is able to read the cookie. I can see the cookie is been created in the browser. 

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !cookie-login=9041;? [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ https://YOURWEBSITE.COM [NC,L]

Comment: "I am wondering if .htaccess file is able to read the cookie." - If `.htaccess` can't read the cookie then the cookie is not being sent on the request that that server receives. Have you confirmed you see the relevant `Cookie` header in the HTTP request? Are you behind a front-end proxy/CDN/load balancer? _Aside:_ "The above code always goes to else clause and redirects to example.com" - There is no "else" clause here. If you are always redirected to `example/google.com` then that is effectively the "if" clause (you have one condition with one rule).

Comment: Thanks @MrWhite. I found my mistake finally. I places the .htaccess file in subfolder and it was not reading the cookie. now i placed in root folder and it started working.

Comment: @SuneelKumarP Glad you got it fixed. Please add that as a self-answer below (you can later accept it) as this might help future readers. Thanks.